# How to add second Pydantic schema into Fastapi endpoint as an option

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, schema, pydantic

Ok. Guys I can't figure it out. Is any option to add second Pydantic schema option, or switch between 2 Pydantic schemas according of parameter in request?
What I want to archieve. If paremeter equals 'all' I would like to add 'date' field into schema.
And if parameter is 'None' I would like to exclude 'data' field at all.
With code below with no parameter at all got: "date": null

```
[
  {
    "unit": "Xeikon 1",
    "color": 65817763,
    "bw": 552903,
    "date": null
  },
  {
    "unit": "Xeikon 2",
    "color": 65825687,
    "bw": 552903,
    "date": null
  },
  {
    "unit": "Xeikon 3",
    "color": 65825784,
    "bw": 552903,
    "date": null
  }
]
```

This is part of my code

```
class Clicks(BaseModel):
    unit: str
    color: int
    bw: int
    date: Optional[date]
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

@xeikon_api.get('/xeikon/clicks/', response_model=List[schema.Clicks])
async def xeikon_Clicks_data(details: Optional[str]=None) :
    """
     endpoint: list all Clicks data \n
    """
    try:
        if details == 'all':
            return db.session.query(Clicks).all()
        if details is None:
            from main import session_local
            response = session_local.query(Clicks)
            return reorganizeClicksData(response)
    except NoResultFound as n:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
            detail=n.orig.args,
            ) from n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you describe it, that would be two distinct response schemas. Therefore you would have to define two distinct models for the response.

Let me quote the relevant [section of the FastAPI docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/extra-models/#union-or-anyof):

> You can declare a response to be the `Union` of two types, that means, that the response would be any of the two. It will be defined in OpenAPI with `anyOf`. To do that, use the standard Python type hint `typing.Union`.

To simplify your example a bit, here is a possible solution:

```py
from datetime import date
from typing import Optional, Union

from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Clicks(BaseModel):
    unit: str
    color: int
    bw: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class ExtendedClicks(Clicks):
    date: date

AnyClicks = Union[list[ExtendedClicks], list[Clicks]]

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/clicks")
async def endpoint(details: Optional[str] = None) -> AnyClicks:
    # Get the clicks data:
    test_data = [
        {"unit": "foo", "color": 1, "bw": 1, "date": "2023-05-10"},
        {"unit": "bar", "color": 0, "bw": 0, "date": "2023-01-01"},
    ]
    if details == "all":
        return [ExtendedClicks.parse_obj(obj) for obj in test_data]
    if details is None:
        return [Clicks.parse_obj(obj) for obj in test_data]
    raise HTTPException(400)
```

The order in the type union is **important**. Since `ExtendedClicks` is a subtype of `Clicks` and it simply ignores extra values, if we were to switch the order in `AnyClicks`, the response would always match `Clicks` and you would never see the `date` field.

The response in this example with the `details=all` query:

```json
[
  {
    "unit": "foo",
    "color": 1,
    "bw": 1,
    "date": "2023-05-10"
  },
  {
    "unit": "bar",
    "color": 0,
    "bw": 0,
    "date": "2023-01-01"
  }
]
```

With no query parameters:

```json
[
  {
    "unit": "foo",
    "color": 1,
    "bw": 1
  },
  {
    "unit": "bar",
    "color": 0,
    "bw": 0
  }
]
```

---

I would still recommend *not* doing that, i.e. not using a union of return types. There is no way to express via the OpenAPI schema that the *response* schema depends on specific query parameters. So all that one can see from the endpoint schema is that it may return a list of `Clicks` and it also may return a list of `ExtendedClicks`.

From an API design standpoint I would recommend just having two separate endpoints for the two distinct schemas.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm still learning where's the border between simplifying the code and still keep it readable and clean. Ok I see now that 2 separate endpoints makes a more sens right here